# Why does C# handle command line args inconsistently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line

In C#, getting command line arguments directly from Main() omits the exe name, contrary to the tradition of C.

Getting those same command line args via Environment.GetCommandLineArgs includes it.

Is there some good logical reason I'm missing for this apparent inconsistency?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("args.Length = {0}", args.Length));

        foreach(string arg in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("args = {0}", arg));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        string[] Eargs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Eargs.Length = {0}", Eargs.Length));
        foreach (string arg in Eargs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Eargs = {0}", arg));
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug>consoleapplication1 xx zz aa 
args.Length = 3 
args = xx
args = zz 
args = aa
Eargs.Length = 4 
Eargs = consoleapplication1 
Eargs = xx 
Eargs = zz 
Eargs = aa
```

Comment: first of all it is not c# but .net framework

Comment: It's not inconsistent, it's just two different ways of doing things.  The former doesn't return the executable and the latter does.  They serve different purposes.

Comment: and it is documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Answer (score 15):

Because it isn't C and thus isn't tied to it's conventions. Needing the exe name is pretty much an edge case; the small number of times I've needed this (compared to the other args) IMO justifies the decision to omit it.

This is additionally demanded in the spec (ECMA334v4, §10.1); (snipping to relevant parts):

> ## 10. Basic concepts
>
> ### 10.1 Application startup

...

> This entry point method is always named `Main`, and shall have one of the 
>   following signatures:

```
static void Main() {…} 
static void Main(string[] args) {…} 
static int Main() {…} 
static int Main(string[] args) {…}
```

...

> • Let `args` be the name of the parameter. If the length of the array designated by `args` is greater than 
>   zero, the array members `args[0]` through `args[args.Length-1]`, inclusive, shall refer to strings, 
>   called ***application parameters***, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment 
>   prior to application startup. The intent is to supply to the application information determined prior to 
>   application startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of 
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that the 
>   strings are received in lowercase. [*Note*: On systems supporting a command line, application, application parameters 
>   correspond to what are generally known as command-line arguments. *end note*]

Comment: + they gave you a way to get it (several really)

Comment: I think the question is still valid. Why differentiate between the args array and Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() result. Forgetting about C, why is there a difference with these two methods?

Comment: @BFree it's about reducing complexity. When you normally process command line events, you don't need other crap that has to be excluded. Think `foreach(string in args)` versus `for(int i=1;i<args.length;i++){process(args[i]);}` (even tho foreach-in may be a poorer strategy, the concept is what I want you to consider)

Comment: @drachenstern: I agree with the idea that the executable name is *rarely* useful, but just to take this argument a bit further, why then DID they include the executable name in the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()? Shouldn't they have kept it consistent? If it were me, I would have kept them the same, and possibly had a separate read-only property like "Environment.ExecutableName" or whatever....

Comment: @BFree ~ That's a question for the likes of Eric Lippert ;)

Comment: @drachenstern: Fair enough. But just to know the OP because "this isn't C" doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @BFree ~ True, but I don't know the _why_ of the team's decision. I merely know it was intentional. That should be enough to me. This isn't C2005 after all, it's C# an ECMA standard language and it has its own specification. All I can do is say "ok, this is how it is". I can't see where he would want to know more other than that definition?

Comment: @drachenstern: That's perfectly fine. All I was trying to point out is that "This isn't C" doesn't really address his question. It may very well be a question none of us can answer, in which case yes, it's a pointless question to ask here, but then that should be the answer. </beating_dead_horse>

Comment: Additionally, thumbing through ECMA 334 there is no provision for Main() arguments.

Comment: Sorry I mentioned C, which has nothing to do with this really. To me the confusion caused by having two different arglengths and arg lists for essentially the same thing outweighs needing to simply ignore the exe name when I don't care about it. And I for one do want to know the "why", almost always, and especially if what appears to me to be a potentially confusing and time wasting inconsistency may actually have a benefit I've overlooked. I'm open to reason or I wouldn't have asked, but the responses so far have not convinced me that there is one. Or even addressed the question.

Comment: I am stunned that this response is continually being up-voted. It does not answer the question at all. "This isn't C" is entirely beside the point. "the decision to omit it" misses the point. The fact that it is mentioned in the documentation is not the point. Am I really so inarticulate that no one understood what the question actually was? Waleed at least understands the question and emphasizes the subjectiveness of his response, even though I find his explanation less than 100% satisfactory.

Comment: "thumbing through ECMA 334 there is no provision for Main() arguments" This may point to a partial explanation. If the only and official ECMA 334 method of getting command line args is Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(), then the (familiar to old school C programmers) ability to get them via main() is just an extra that Microsoft threw into its implementation of C#, and of course need not conform to anything. However, this does not explain why something included only because it would be familiar and expected would not be implemented in the familiar and expected way.

Comment: @mickeyf - it addresses the point of the *original question* ; you then edited and changed the question... #

Comment: @mickeyf @drachenstern - ECMA 334v4, see section 10.1 where it covers this in detail, and describes how they map to arguments. No mention is name of the exe.

Comment: @marc I have not edited the question. Unless edited by someone else (and I see no changes) it stands as originally entered. I find it very unhelpful when a question is edited in such a way as to remove the original text; My practice is to put an 'addendum' indicating the clarification.

Comment: @mickeys you are right; my apologies. When I scanned it the second time I must have missed the comparison to C, but that is still in the original form. My mistake; sorry.

Comment: @MarcGravell ~ No fair :( I couldn't find that. Now I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[status-by-design]  -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3(v=VS.100).aspx

> Unlike C and C++, the name of the program is not treated as the first command-line argument.

Comment: My difficulty is not with whether it is or is not treated as a command-line argument - I can live with that either way. My difficulty is that in one case it is and that in another case it is not.

Comment: Interesting quote,  right up to the point that a function named GetCommandLineArgs() treats the name of the program as the first command line argument

Answer (score 6):

To me, the reason the two methods return different results is due to `Context`.

- The [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class is used to manipulate the current environement and process, and it makes sense that `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` returns the executable name, since it is part of the process.
- As for the args array, **to me** it makes sense to exclude the executable name. I know that I am calling the executable and in the context of running my application I want to know what arguments were sent to it.

At the end of the day, it is powerful to have a way to get at both alternatives.

Comment: +1 I was mid-answering and saw these post, this is what I was going to mention, its all a matter of perspective(context) of the calls

Comment: People used to do tricks based on the name of the executable to alter execution path since it was included in the arglist. If the file was named move.exe, they would move files by default, if copy.exe, copy by default, etc. Stupid compiler tricks, but done nonetheless.

Comment: er, those weren't compiler tricks but runtime, but whatever, my point still holds.